# Configuring Jupyter default imports

Tags: python, jupyter

How do I tell Jupyter (console and notebook) to import some Python packages by default?  I would like to do this using only the `.jupyter` folder

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I personally couldn't find a way to do so only using the `.jupyter` folder. You have to specify the commands to be executed on startup in the `.ipython` folder anyway:

1. Create `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` if it not exists
2. Add something like this:

   ```
   c = get_config()
   c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
       'import numpy as np\n'
       'import scipy as sp\n'
       'import matplotlib as plt\n'
   ]
   ```

You can also specify any valid commands here, not only imports.

Comment: Ah, okay, for some reason I thought that the .ipython was deprecated in favor of .jupyter since the app now warns me to stop typing ipython.

Comment: Do you know how to point the `jupyter` executable to a specific (non-global) config file?

Comment: For jupyterhub users, this file can go in `/etc/ipython/ipython_config.py` and it will be applied globally.

Comment: ok I have followed the steps above, then run jupyter notebook/lab and do not see any of the default imports loaded.

Comment: It's perhaps nicer to remove the newlines, `\n`, from the strings, and separate them with a comma. After all, `exec_lines` is probably intended to be a list of singe-line strings, not a list of one multi-line string (which it is currently).

Answer (score 22):

A bit of background:

- Jupyter provides the UI/environments such as the console and notebook. It defers to what it calls **kernels** for execution.
- *IPython* provides the default (Python) kernel for Jupyter.
- Jupyter configuration doesn't affect kernels directly, but each kernel may have its own configuration.

The IPython configuration resides in your `.ipython` directory. The quickest way to add code to run on startup of IPython (affects IPython sessions in the terminal and notebook) is to add **startup files** to your IPython profile.

1. Create the default profile, if it doesn't exist already (it probably does):

   ```
   ipython profile create
   ```
2. Make a Python script `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/whateveryouwant.py` and add any imports or other commands in there that you would like to have ready whenever you start IPython. IPython will run this script and any others in that directory every time it starts up.

Comment: Ah, okay, for some reason I thought that the .ipython was deprecated in favor of .jupyter since the app now warns me to stop typing ipython.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. IPython still exists, as does all of its configuration and profiles. What happened was the Notebook and some related components moved to a *new* project called Jupyter. Nothing in IPython's configuration has been deprecated other than its ability to configure and launch the Jupyter applications (i.e. `ipython_notebook_config.py` and the `ipython notebook` command). When you use a Jupyter Notebook with Python, you are using *both* Jupyter and IPython. However, when you use a Jupyter notebook with another language, e.g. Julia, you are not using IPython at all.

Comment: Is there a way to specify cell magics in an ipython startup script? I got an error - "[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling startup files:" - until I removed the "%matplotlib inline" line from my script.

Comment: @gumption Yes, by simply using a .ipy file extension (instead of a .py) extension.

Comment: Is there any way to add some startup code that only affects ipython notebook, not ipython terminal? When I launch ipython, I mostly want to do something quick, so I want to launch it quickly without too many imports. When I launch notebook, I want to do something complicated, and import some code by default, so a little bit slower is acceptable.

Comment: Is there a difference between creating this config file in this startup dir `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` over one level up `~/.ipython/profile_default/`  as proposed by @slippy?