# Integrate Jupyter notebook with data fetched from Django application

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I have a Django application that integrates data from a SQL database and displays that as a downloadable HTML table. Now I would also like to add analysis functionality, but instead of painstakingly adding only a few functionalities using JavaScript, I want to redirect the user to a Jupyter notebook, so the user has full access to the functionality of Python data analysis libraries or even other languages. Now I'm not sure how to approach this and I have several questions:

- Am I right that Jupyter needs to be run on a different server than the Django app since it uses the Tornado server?
- How would I transfer the data produced with Django to Jupyter? I store the data in a new MySQL table, but I would at least need to transfer the table name.
- Given the table name was transferred to Jupyter I would still need to execute custom code to access the database. I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446211/configuring-jupyter-default-imports) that some defaults for code execution can be set in IPython configuration, but since the table from which the data should be loaded is never the same, this would have to be adapted dynamically.

I'm glad for any suggestions and comments on whether this idea makes sense at all.

Comment: It definitely makes sense, and you're right that it would need to be a separate server. I think the best way to do it would be to generate a notebook file (using the [nbformat](http://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package) with an initial cell containing the necessary setup code. Then write it to a file in a location the notebook server can see, and open it in the notebook server by URL.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right that Jupyter needs to be run on a different server than the Django app since it uses the Tornado server?

No. They can run on the same server.

> How would I transfer the data produced with Django to Jupyter? I store the data in a new MySQL table, but I would at least need to transfer the table name.

You can run django and Jupyter together and execute any django code from Jupyter. The easiest way to do so is by using [`shell_plus` from the package *django-extensions*](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html) You can even connect to the production database.

**You should consider the possible security and data safety risks. This is a potential vector for remote code execution and data leaks.**

It's probably safer to spin up a cloned django instance with a cloned database or use a different django configuration (`settings.py`) with read-only access to the db.

It's quite easy to mess up production data from Jupyter, since you can do stuff such as `User.objects.all().delete()` And that would be a problem...

Also consider running this as a user with stricter read and write permissions than you use for your regular django app.

And of course, you should make sure that the Jupyter site is not exposed on a publicly accessible url.

Comment: What kind of server would that be? I was planning to deploy the Django app on Apache. And how would I than redirect the user to the notebook page, if I simply start the notebook from the shell? It's not that I really want to enable the user to execute Django code, I just want to transfer the data generated by the app.

Comment: Yes. When you start the notebook, it spins up a tornado server that listens on for instance `localhost:8888`. You can use apache or nginx to proxy external connections between `jupyter.example.com:80` to  `localhost:8888`, exposing it to the internet. 

There's of course other ways of accessing the data. The advantage with this method is that you get full access to the django ORM. In other words Models and Querysets. But since it's quite powerful, you must also pay more attention to potential security risks.

Comment: I have just played around with this for my own use, so I'm no expert. You can probably find more detailed guides about this by googling **"jupyter public server"** or something like that. Setting it up with nginx was very simple. I assume that it's not too hard with apache either.

Comment: You can also write django views and templates to generate html tables etc. to display in Jupyter output cells using `IPython.display.HTML()`

Comment: Sounds interesting and I will have a closer look at it. Apart from that I could imagine to, as @Tomas K. suggested, just use a view to generate the JSON file for the notebook loaded with the initial data and running two servers in parallel. One would have to make sure that its safe to let people execute code on your server.